# Change in mean of y given change in mean of x?

Tags: regression, interpretation

I am a bit confused about interpreting simple linear regression coefficients. My understanding is that for a linear regression equation, increasing x by one unit corresponds to a change in the mean of y.

What I don’t understand is what is exactly meant by “mean of y.” It can’t be the arithmetic mean of the entire y dataset. Same for the x, I’ve heard the regression line passes through the mean of x and mean of y. How is this the case when different values of x will yield larger values of y (assuming positive slope)? How can it be a static number, or is it?

I am trying to get a better grasp of understanding what a one unit change in x corresponding to a k unit change in y really means because it has lost me at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems of interpretation comes from some sloppy formulations! When you say

> mean of y

it has different meanings in different places! Sometimes it is the **marginal mean** of y, that is, its mean (or in the model, expectation) over all its values, not taking into consideration (that is, conditioning upon) x. But othertimes it is the **conditional mean**, given the corresponding value of x.

Hopefully this is enough of a hint that you can untangle the mistery yourself now.

Comment: I just think it’s a bit weird to call it the “conditional mean” considering a situation where we have, say, only 3 coordinate pairs. How would the conditional mean of y given x be interpreted then?